# FullCalendar display within date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to display [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) withing a certain date range. To do so I added the following `visibleRange` option to my code but it is not working. The calendar is simply not displaying.

```js
this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
  //other settings
            
  defaultView: 'basic',
  visibleRange: {
    start: moment('2017-05-22'),
    end: moment('2017-05-29')
  },
  duration: { days: 7 },
            
  //other settings
});
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery/momentjs/fullcalendar are you using? Also, this.$calendar.fullCalendar syntax... are you using something else in the mix?

Did you try invoking it as **this.$calendar.fullCalendar();** and seeing if the calendar displays? Checked the console for any errors or warnings?

Comment: I am using fullCalendar 3.0.1 backbone.js 1.2.3 moment.js 2.9.0
this.$calendar.fullCalendar(); is for calling full calendar in backbone.
Console did not show any errors in particalurAR

Answer (score 3):

Using momentjs 2.18.1, jquery 3.2.1, fullcalendar 3.4.0 this shows the view from 5/22 through 5/28:

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'basic',
    visibleRange: {
      start: moment('2017-05-22'),
      end: moment('2017-05-29')
    } // Don't use duration in combination with visibleRange? Appears to override
    /*,
    duration: {
      days: 7
    }*/
  });
```

Demo @ https://jsfiddle.net/ez33y8gv/